# Unable to access contents of initialized struct from a vector

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, vector

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    Qt::Key qKey;
    QString strFormType;
} KeyPair;
```

Now I initialize KeyPair instantiations so I could use it for my Automated Test App.

```
KeyPair gTestMenu[] =
{
    { Qt::Key_1 , "MyForm" },
    { Qt::Key_1 , "SubForm" },
    { Qt::Key_Escape, "DesktopForm" }
};

KeyPair gBrowseMenu[] =
{
    { Qt::Key_1 , "MyForm" },
    { Qt::Key_2 , "Dialog" },
    { Qt::Key_Escape, "DesktopForm" }
};

and like 100 more instantiations....
```

Currently, I call a function which uses these KeyPairs.

```
pressKeyPairs( gTestMenu );
pressKeyPairs( gBrowseMenu );
and more calls for the rest...
```

I would like to put all these KeyPair instantiations in a vector so I wouldn't have to call pressKeyPairs() a hundred times... I'm a newbie in using vectors... so I tried:

```
std::vector<KeyPair, std::allocator<KeyPair> > vMasterList;
vMasterList.push_back( *gTestMenu );
vMasterList.push_back( *gBrowseMenu );

std::vector<KeyPair, std::allocator<KeyPair> >::iterator iKeys;
for(iKeys = vMasterList.begin(); iKeys != vMasterList.end(); ++iKeys)
{
    pressKeyPairs(*iKeys);
}
```

However, this code block isn't working... :( Can somebody tell me how to properly put these KeyPairs in a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use `insert` to populate the vector with your different arrays. Here is how you should do it.

```
//initialized with one array
std::vector<KeyPair> vMasterList(gTestMenu, gTestMenu + 3);

//adding more items
vMasterList.insert( vMasterList.end(),  gBrowseMenu , gBrowseMenu  + 3);
```

And then reimplement your `pressKeyPair` function, so that you can use `std::for_each`  from `<algorithm>` header file as,

```
 //pressKeyPair will be called for each item in the list!
 std::for_each(vMasterList.begin(), vMasterList.end(), pressKeyPair);
```

Here is how you can write the `pressKeyPair` function:

```
  void pressKeyPair(KeyPair &keyPair) //takes just one item!
  {
       //press key pair!
  }
```

In my opinion, this is better design, as it doesn't need "manual" loop anymore at the calling site!

You can even call `pressKeyPair` for first 5 items in the list as,

```
 //pressKeyPair will be called for first 5 items in the list!
 std::for_each(vMasterList.begin(), vMasterList.begin() + 5, pressKeyPair);
```

One more example:

```
 //pressKeyPair will be called for 5 items after the first 5 items, in the list!
 std::for_each(vMasterList.begin()+5, vMasterList.begin() + 10, pressKeyPair);
```

---

EDIT:

If you want to use manual loop, then you've to use this:

```
std::vector<KeyPair>::iterator it;
for( it = vMasterList.begin(); it != vMasterList.end(); ++it)
{
    pressKeyPair(*it);
}
```

But I would say it's not as elegant as the approach described earlier. Remember, this assumes that the function `pressKeyPair` has this signature:

```
void pressKeyPair(KeyPair &keyPair); //it doesn't accept array!
```

Comment: In std::vector<KeyPair> vMasterList(gTestMenu, gTestMenu + 3); where did 3 come from? thanks... :)

Comment: @Owen: This is how you have initialized `gTestMenu`. `gTestMenu` contains 3 items. I'm using that. :-)

Comment: Thanks Nawaz... What if I do a manual loop? how do I do that? The loop I tried didn't work... :(

Comment: Hi Nawaz, you're right... manual loop doesn't work for me. So I'm going for your elegant approach. The way I implemented pressKeyPair is : template <size_t nNumOfElements> void pressKeyPair (KeyPair (&gKeys)[nNumOfElements]); so I could get the size of the KeyPair as well. However, when I use the for_each for this I'm getting this error message... :(

Comment: Here's the error message: : Error 2 no matching function for call to ‘for_each(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<KeyPair*, std::vector<KeyPair, std::allocator<KeyPair> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<KeyPair*, std::vector<KeyPair, std::allocator<KeyPair> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’

Comment: @Owen: No. Don't implement pressKeyPair like that. No No No if you want to follow my approach. In my approach, pressKeyPair accepts only one item at a time, and this function gets called for all items in the list. Just see my post. It explains it well.

Comment: @Nawaz: will I still be able to get the size of KeyPair when I use void pressKeyPair(KeyPair &keyPair)? thanks...

Comment: @Owen: What size are you talking about? Do you need `sizeof` ? or what? Why do you even need it?

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm refering to the number of items in each KeyPair. Each KeyPair's number of items vary. gTestMenu has 3, gTrial has 7, etc... Inside pressKeyPair, I get the number of items of the KeyPairs so I could loop through the list and I know where to stop... :)

Comment: @Owen: If you follow my approach of pressKeyPair, then this function takes JUST ONE keypair. Just One. Inside pressKeyPair, you assume that you have only one instance of KeyPair. Did you see the signature of `pressKeyPair` in my post? It takes just one instance. **There should not be loop inside pressKeyPair.** You need to change your function, if you want to follow my approach!

Comment: @Owen: If you come to gtalk, then I'll explain it there.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that the code

```
vMasterList.push_back( *gTestMenu );
```

Only adds a single element of `gTestMenu` to the vector, namely the first.  The reason is that this code is equivalent to the following:

```
vMasterList.push_back( gTestMenu[0] );
```

From which I think it's a bit easier to see what's going wrong.

To fix this, you probably want to add all of the elements in `gTestMenu` to the master list.  You can do this using the three-parameter `vector::insert` function:

```
vMasterList.insert(v.begin(),  // Insert at the beginning
                   gTestMenu,  // From the start of gTestMenu...
                   gTestMenu + kNumTests); // ... to the end of the list
```

Here, you'll need to specify how many tests are in `gTestMenu` as `kNumTests`.  You can do the same for `gBrowseMenu`.

By the way, you don't need to specify the allocator type in the `vector` declaration if you just want to use the default `std::allocator`.  You can just write

```
std::vector<KeyPair> vMasterList;
```

And you'll be totally fine.